# sugarcrm inboundemail not creating cases

Tags: email, case, sugarcrm, creation, inbound

I have created a Group Mail Account and checked by clicking 'Test Settings' which says 'Connection Completed Successfully'. Then I set the scheduler for 'Check Inbound Mail Accounts' to run after every one minute. But this is not working for me. Cases are not being created, although the status of this scheduler is 'completed' every time.

I have set the cron job to echo any error in file where it writes the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: InboundEmail::$team_id in
>   /var/www/crm31/modules/Schedulers/_AddJobsHere.php on line 100

Can anybody please suggest me where I am wrong or what I am missing? Where and how to set this team_id?

I am using CRM CE 6.4 on ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question was asked a long time ago, but I was just searching for this exact problem and it brought me here.

I ended up solving this by running cron.php with curl. So instead of running

```
php.exe -f cron.php
```

I run

```
curl http://yoursugarinstall/cron.php
```

You might also have to comment out a CLI only check in the cron.php file on line 45